# How to store image in Firebase on long press? I have a listview of images

Tags: flutter

I have a doubt regarding what to use. When user long press an image the name of the image should be stored in firebase and I'm using multiple images in a list view, how can I create such feature?

Comment: Add the code of what you've done so far

Comment: maybe use a gesture detector to detect long press and upload name to firebase? since you have not shared your approach/code we can't help much either.